# Calling into or between controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some fairly complicated logic in a bootstrap dialog which I've moved into its own controller for isolation.

There are times I want to launch the dialog or call a function in the controller based on some logic that occurs elsewhere in the app - in another controller, or a service. I've achieved this by adding an id to the ng-controller element then looking up the element by that id, and calling things off the .scope() of that controller. Essentially this:

In html:

`<div id="modalController" ng-controller="modalController">`

And in another service or controller:

`angular.element("#modalController").scope().somefunction()`

This seems pretty weird that I can't just get a controller by name. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your description is a little hard to understand, but I would suggest possibly using "broadcast" and "on".

Comment: @ZackArgyle I'm happy to clarify - what part is hard to understand?

Answer (score 1):

Create a service and bind the model to data maintained in that service.  Make a change to the model within the service and it's made everywhere.

You could also create a service that provides a pubsub interface to the changes you need to make.

Yet another way to do it would be to have a single model representing the state of your system and modify that.  Attach the relevant parts of that model to the scopes of each widget as necessary and you have a communication device built in.

It sounds like you are making a change in one place that should cause a change in another place.  If that's the case, I'd argue having a service that updates all parts of the model correctly is the best way to go.  Always imagine what you'd do if you added another widget that hangs off this functionality.

Comment: I was using this at first, but I had a "openModal" and "closeModal" boolean to control each dialog I want to open. It feels a little heavy.

Comment: From that description, it feels like the modals should be directly controlled by the service.